# php mysql sort specific "list view" column based on a passed value - specified by end user - after initial "Order By" provided in query

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm trying to create a sort feature/link for end users so they can view the "list view" content - based on clicking and passing the field/header value along with either ASC or DESC - back to same page. They choose to view the list by sorting first_name or last_name or age - or any other column item they need to see the list view by.

Below is a query from 10 years ago that worked great, but doesn't work in the modern php environment(?) using pageParameter. I liked the feature, just cant get it to work in modern environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

example of old query...

```
"select * from players where players.region_id = " . $_GET["region_id"] . " order by " . pageParameter("SortBy","players.player_lname") . ""
```

example column header image with link to

```
pabe.php?SortBy=team_id&region_id=<?php echo $regions->Value("region_id") ?>' target="_self"><img src="../image/arrow.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="6"> end of link
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable for SQL injection - but apart from that, what exactly doesn't work? Please also show the implementation of the pageParameter function.

Comment: Function is old, using globals, it's what doesn't work.

Comment: // Position a content source at the end.  Designed for hand-coders.
function MoveToEnd(&$cs)
{
 $cs->MoveTo($cs->RecordCount()+1);
}

function pageParameter($name, $defaultValue)
{
 if (@$GLOBALS[$name] <> "") {
  return @$GLOBALS[$name];
 } else {
  return $defaultValue;
 }
}

Comment: I tried to turn $GLOBALS into $_GET, but no luck in getting it to work.

Comment: function pageParameter($name, $defaultValue)
{
 if (@$_GET[$name] <> "") {
  return @$_GET[$name];
 } else {
  return $defaultValue;
 }
}

Comment: the list is also inside a form holder

Comment: So the results are always sorted by the default value (player_lname) instead of the field passed as `SortBy`? I don't see why it shouldn't work using $_GET. Try to dump the contents of $_GET as well as the generated query (`var_dump($_GET, $query)`) - maybe this helps identifying the problem.

Comment: the order by is the original state, then sort by is based on the user selecting any of the column headers to sort by.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get what your actual problem is. Users can sort data by clicking a column header - so far so good - but what happens if they do so? Is there an error? Or is the data just not sorted correctly? Please be more specific and provide the debug info I asked for (the var_dump).

Comment: It was old code, and I am not able to get it to work today in the modern php  environment. My result is white screen.

Comment: The white screen indicates that a fatal error occurred and error reporting is turned off. Check your PHP error log or activate error reporting.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it should work, It gave me the strength to stick with it and I got it to work!